# jQuery carry var through functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

> #### Note:
>
> This was merely a syntactical error question.

---

I have a var array that I've created here:

```
function(){
    var arr = {};

    ...
}
```

Below that, I've created a jQuery function:

```
function(){
    var arr = {};

    $("div").each(function(){
        arr.push("something") //Not in scope, breaks.
    });
}
```

Inside that function, I want to push an element to the array, but it is not in the scope of the jQuery function. How can I pass `arr` to the function bound to the `.each()`?

Comment: `{}` is an object not an array which is `[]`, and arr would be in viewable scope, you are just trying to call a method that object does not have

Comment: Pardon me. It's late and I mis-typed. However, can I still pass the array through?

Comment: You can pass the array through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on your original question:** You have defined `arr` using `{}`. That makes it a generic object, not an array. Generic objects don't have a `push` method. To create an array, use `[]`.

This works just fine:

```
function(){
    var arr = [];

    $("div").each(function(){
        arr.push("something") //Not in scope, breaks.
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow, so my problem was literally just a syntax problem. Hahaha. Thanks :P